# ActiveRecord associations and scopes oh my

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, scopes

I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from multiple tables and making sense of it.

I have `events`, `occurrences` and `venues` tables.

Here are the models/associations so far:

models/event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :occurences, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :price
 belongs_to :venue
 validates_presence_of :venue
end
```

models/venue.rb:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

models/occurence.rb:

```
class Occurence < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to  :event
 scope :today, lambda { where("occurence.datetime_start <= ? AND datetime_end >= ?", Time.now.end_of_day, Time.now) }
 scope :this_week, lambda { where("occurence.datetime_start <= ? AND datetime_end <= ?", Time.now.end_of_day, Time.now.at_end_of_week) }
 scope :next_week, lambda { where("occurence.datetime_start > ? AND datetime_end < ?", Time.now.at_end_of_week, Time.now.at_end_of_week + 1.weeks) }
 scope :this_month, lambda { where("occurence.datetime_start <= ? AND datetime_end >= ?", Time.now.end_of_day, Time.now.at_end_of_month) }
 scope :next_month, lambda { where("occurence.datetime_start >= ? AND datetime_end <= ?", Time.now.at_beginning_of_month + 1.months, Time.now.at_end_of_month + 1.months) }
end
```

What I'd like to show in my view/events/index.html.erb is a table of all events happening today and I like to do something like:

```
<% @events.today.each do |event|  %>
```

and display all the events that match the `.today` scope.

I tried moving the scope to the `event` model to no avail. Should I move the scopes to the event model? So far my searches have lead me to
"[Using scope to return results within multiple DateTime ranges in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751011/using-scope-to-return-results-within-multiple-datetime-ranges-in-activerecord)"
and
"[Multiple scope in rails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007547/multiple-scope-in-rails-3-0)"  but I can't really make anything out of it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Should I create a new function in my event model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occurences, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :price
  belongs_to :venue
  validates_presence_of :venue

  scope :today, lambda {
    joins(:occurences).where("datetime_start <= ? AND datetime_end >= ?", Time.now.end_of_day, Time.now)
  }
end
```

Comment: I have found, after further testing, that the above scope is returning multiple identical event (as many as there are matched occurences per event). I'd like to have the event returned only once even if many occurences match the scope. How can this be done?

Example: An event has many occurrences throughout the month (say 10) the the @events = Event.all output will generate 10 entries for that event.

Comment: You could try chaining a .select("distinct `events`.*") to the value of the scope.

Comment: You sir, are a pro. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your syntax to work like:

```
@events.today
```

Then the scope would have to be in the `Event` model.

If you're OK with:

```
@event.occurences.today
```

then you're OK now,  i.e.:

```
@events = Event.all
@events.each do |ev|
   ev.occurences.today.each do |oc|
   end
end
```